# How to retrieve Tweet replies/comments of a particular user using Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy, information-retrieval, twitterapi-python

This is the code I've tried and I want a solution apart from this one

```
def replies_from_tweet_id(tweet_id,username):
  replies=[]
  for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='to:'+username, result_type='recent',timeout=999999,tweet_mode='extended',count=3000).items():
    if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
      if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==str(tweet_id)):
          replies.append(tweet)

  
  with open('./Data/'+username+'/'+tweet_id+'.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('text','date'))
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for tweet in replies[:200]:
        row = {'text': tweet.full_text.replace('\n', ' ').strip('@'+username),'date':tweet.created_at }
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Twitter API v2, you can query by [conversation ID](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id) to retrieve Tweets from a specific conversation thread.

Comment: Do you know how to resolve 429: too many request error?

Comment: That's not relevant to this question. You're encountering a rate limit.